# My code says it has no errors yet will not run

Tags: java

```
import java.util.*;

public class e2a {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String scf;
        String sCF = "CF";
        String sFC = "FC";
        int iTemp;
        int iConvTemp;

        Scanner sin = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.println("Please indicate what conversion you would like to make. Enter CF for Centigrade to Fahrenheit. Enter FC for Fahrenheit to Centigrade.");
        scf = sin.next();

        System.out.println("Please enter the temperature you would like to convert.");
        iTemp = sin.nextInt();

        if((scf).equals("CF")) 
        {     iConvTemp = (((iTemp*9)/5)+32);
              System.out.println(iTemp + " in Fahrenheit is : " + iConvTemp);
        }
        else if((scf).equals("FC"))
        {     iConvTemp = (((iTemp-32)*5)/9);
              System.out.println(iTemp + " in Centigrade is : " + iConvTemp);
        }
    }
}
```

> The goal is to get user to input the direction and number they would like to convert and then use if statements to output the correct value

Comment: What do you mean by "says it has no errors" and "will not run"?

Comment: How are you trying to run it?

Comment: Everything seems fine, maybe you are running it wrong, or you run it corrently and then you don't type your input so it doesn't do anything else.

Comment: Also works fine for me.  Please [edit] your question to include information about how you are compiling and running your program.

Answer (score 0):

Hey so I just found out that it was my computer, I ran it on a different one and it worked just fine. Thank you very much. I had to reboot my compiler yo get it working again.